# $f(x)=\sum_0^\infty (-1)^n\frac{1}{(n!)^2}(\frac{x}{2})^{2n}$ $\implies$ $f''+\frac{f'}{x}+f=0$

Tags: real-analysis

I would like to prove this function $f(x)=\sum_0^\infty (-1)^n\frac{1}{(n!)^2}(\frac{x}{2})^{2n}$ has the following property:

> $f''+\frac{f'}{x}+f=0$

I know this convergence ray is $\infty$ but I couldn't prove that this property holds, I've already expanded the function, but It's not zero, maybe there is a trick or something to solve it.

I need help

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If the property is correct (I haven't checked), it will surely follow from a term by term differentiation.

Comment: @julien I've already done this, but it's never zero.

Comment: @user42912: Why not show your work?  That way we can see if there was a mistake in your work, or if it can be adjusted so that it does work.

Comment: Ok, I've checked, it works.

Comment: @julien thank you, I will try again

Answer (score 4):

Differentiating term by term, we find after some reindexing:
$$
\frac{f'(x)}{x}=\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{n+1}{((n+1)!)^22^{2n+1}}x^{2n}
$$
and
$$
f''(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{(n+1)(2n+1)}{((n+1)!)^22^{2n+1}}x^{2n}.
$$

Now adding term by term $f''(x)+f'(x)/x+f(x)$, we find that the coefficient of $x^{2n}$ is $(-1)^n$ times the following
$$
\frac{2(n+1)^2-(n+1)-(n+1)(2n+1)}{((n+1)!)^22^{2n+1}}=\frac{(n+1)(2(n+1)-1-(2n+1))}{((n+1)!)^22^{2n+1}}=0.
$$

So $f$ does satisfy the given ODE.

Comment: you said $f''(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{(n+1)(2n+1)}{((n+1)!)^22^{2n+1}}x^{2n}$, it's not $f''(x)=\sum_{n\geq 1}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{(n+1)(2n+1)}{((n+1)!)^22^{2n+1}}x^{2n}$? beginning in $n=1$

Comment: @user42912 You have $f(x)=1-x^2/4+\ldots$, so $f''(x)=-1/2+\ldots$. So it really starts at $n=0$.